# Steglich Esterification in Alkyl Gallates

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis, esters, phenols

Based on my research (reading some articles), some alkyl gallate syntheses used Steglich esterification instead of the usual esterification (Fischer esterification). The reason why Steglich esterification is used is because it allows the conversion of sterically demanding and acid-labile substrates.

However, I didn't understand which substrates are sterically demanding or acid-labile in alkyl gallate syntheses.

**My question:**
If I want to synthesize ethyl gallate, isobutyl gallate, and hexyl gallate, do I need to do Steglich esterification? or I can just do the usual esterification (Fischer esterification)?

**Note:**
Alkyl gallate synthesis uses alcohol and gallic acid to produce alkyl gallate

Comment: Who still uses Fischer? Well, there's bound to be some, but I doubt it was still *the usual* method for many decades.

Comment: As far as gallates (lowercase!) are concerned, [gallic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallic_acid) itself is too sensitive for heating it with H2SO4 - it can be oxidised even by air!

Comment: This paper appears from the abstract to be relevant  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/recl.19510700310

Comment: Thanks for answering, I think it already answered my problem